# Return bool if a string shares all characters with another string including doubles Python-3.x

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm sorry if a similar problem has been asked, I could not find it.

I need to check whether `string_a` contains all the characters from `string_b` including the non-unique ones.

Example 1:

```
... string_a = 'baba'
... string_b = 'baaa'
... <solution here>
False
```

Example 2 (returns `True` because now `string_a` has enough `'a'`s):

```
... string_a = 'ababa'
... string_b = 'baaa'
... <solution here>
True
```

I tried `set()` method but it only works if the characters of the strings are unique. So I have this:

```
... string_a = 'baba'
... string_b = 'baaa'
... return set(string_b) <= set(string_a)
True
```

I want it to be `False` because `string_b` has three `'a'`s and `string_a` only two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing is interpreting the strings as [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) and checking if one is a subset of the other. Python's multiset representation is [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('baba')
Counter({'b': 2, 'a': 2})
>>> Counter('baaa')
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 1})
```

Unfortunately, `Counter` doesn't implement a `is_subset` method, so we have to write our own. Here are two ways to do it:

```
def is_sub_multiset(haystack, needle):
    haystack = Counter(haystack)
    needle = Counter(needle)

    return not needle - haystack
    # OR
    # return all(haystack[elem] >= count for elem, count in needle.items())
```

```
>>> is_sub_multiset('baba', 'baaa')
False
>>> is_sub_multiset('ababa', 'baaa')
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Counter as a solution seems best to me.

First count all characters in string_a, then go through string_b char by char and substract from the counter or fail if counter=0. This allows us to get a solution in O(n), reading each string once.

```
from collections import Counter

def is_subset(string_a, string_b):
  count = Counter(string_a)
  for c in string_b:
    if count[c] == 0:
      return False
    count[c] -= 1
  return True


print(is_subset('baba', 'baaa')) # =>False
print(is_subset('ababa', 'baaa')) # =>True
print(is_subset('aabb', 'd')) # =>False
print(is_subset('aabb', 'bbb')) # =>False
```